# VERCEL DEPLOYMENT ERROR: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/vercel/path0/src'"

Tags: reactjs, deployment, module, vercel

I have been getting this error after pushing a new update to my already deployed React Project Project on Vercel.
After trying several ways to resolve it and all proved abortive I decided to delete the deployment and redeploy it completely and I still ran into same issue.

```
[11:46:57.878] Cloning github.com/eimaam/myPortfolio (Branch: main, Commit: e7ba338
[\[11:46:59.279\] Cloning completed: 1.401s
\[11:46:59.646\] No Build Cache available
\[11:46:59.702\] Running "vercel build"
\[11:47:00.346\] Vercel CLI 28.4.7
\[11:47:00.715\] Installing dependencies...
\[11:47:14.317\] npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
\[11:47:14.322\] npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
\[11:47:25.008\] npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
\[11:47:35.787\] 
\[11:47:35.787\] added 1470 packages in 35s
\[11:47:35.788\] 
\[11:47:35.788\] 204 packages are looking for funding
\[11:47:35.788\]   run `npm fund` for details
\[11:47:35.844\] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
\[11:47:35.844\] Running "npm run build"
\[11:47:36.222\] 
\[11:47:36.222\] > profile@0.1.0 build
\[11:47:36.222\] > react-scripts build
\[11:47:36.222\] 
\[11:47:37.956\] Creating an optimized production build...
\[11:47:38.935\] Failed to compile.
\[11:47:38.935\] 
\[11:47:38.935\] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/vercel/path0/src'
\[11:47:38.935\] 
\[11:47:38.936\] 
\[11:47:38.966\] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried these commands, and it worked for me:**

**1- git rm -r --cached**
Remove all files and directories from the Git repository's index, but keep them in your local file system.

**2- git add --all**
Add all files and directories, including untracked files, to the Git repository's index.

**3- git commit -a -m "Versioning untracked files"**
Create a new commit that includes all changes in the index, including modifications and deletions. The commit message is "Versioning untracked files".

**4- git push origin master**
Push the local commits to the remote repository named "origin" and the branch "master". Sync your local changes with the remote repository.